# how to web scrape autocompleting textfield

Tags: java, autocomplete, web-scraping, jsoup, htmlunit

I am trying to fill a website form(compareraja.in) to search and compare mobile phones using java. I currently am using the jaunt library, but I just cant get to know, how to fill an autocompleting textfield, what i want is to select a particular item from the autocompleting list after i apply a certain initial letters to the textfield. Is it possible with jsoup or jaunt or htmlunit or any other library?

if yes, which is the most better and easiest choice ? Also how can it be done?

[image: Image of the autocompleting textfield]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My clue is that first of all you have to retrieve the whole autocompletion list which appears after you've applied a certain letters. If you open the web page in e. g. Chrome, go to Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd>, Network Tab, then you will see that each time you type a letter in the textfield, a corresponding **X**ML **H**TTP **R**equest is logged in the list.

For example, I've typed "htc ":

[image: compare products autocompletion]

On the Network Tab the last one XHR Header section contains all the necessary query parameters :

[image: request]

And Response section shows the received data, which is actually being shown in that autocompletion list:

[image: response]

So, you can just make GET XHR to URL [`http://www.compareraja.in/autocompletedata.ashx?q=htc+&c=mobiles&limit=150`](http://www.compareraja.in/autocompletedata.ashx?q=htc%20&c=mobiles&limit=150) (you can even click this link or paste it to the browser's address line to test), where your URL-encoded initial letters should be placed instead of `htc+`. It works fine without `timestamp` parameter for me.

After that it's easy to parse the response, splitting text by `\n` and `;` chars, and fill the textfield with selected item.

Comment: Thanx a lot omegastripes.